# Remove standard css classes of checkout field wrappers in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bootstrap-4, checkout

I'm building an eCommerce website based on Wordpress and Woocommerce. So far everything is going great, but on the last page of the chec-out (billing and shipping), the standard classes of Woocommerce are interfering with the markup of Bootstrap 4.

Every field in the billing form is wrapped by a

tag with at least the class form-row (i.e.):

```
class="form-row form-row-first"
```

This causes the forms to '"fall" of of the standard BS grid.

Anyone knows how to remove these wrapper classes?

Thanks a bunch,

Cheers,
Nicky

Comment: You can do something complicated by editing the internal files of these templates or you can just override in `css` and save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clean the `class="form-row form-row-first"` from the `<p>` tag fields container, the following code will do the job on checkout fields:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_country', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_state', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_textarea', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_checkbox', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_password', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_text', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_email', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_tel', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_number', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_select', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_radio', 'clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values', 20, 4);
function clean_checkout_fields_class_attribute_values( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    if( is_checkout() ){
        // remove "form-row"
        $field = str_replace( array('<p class="form-row ', '<p class="form-row'), array('<p class="', '<p class="'), $field);
    }

    return $field;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_fields_class_attribute_value', 20, 1);
function custom_checkout_fields_class_attribute_value( $fields ){
    foreach( $fields as $fields_group_key => $group_fields_values ){
        foreach( $group_fields_values as $field_key => $field ){
            // Remove other classes (or set yours)
            $fields[$fields_group_key][$field_key]['class'] = array(); 
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Hey. I'm trying to get the values contained in the form elements by the following code..

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'addBootstrapToCheckoutFields' );
function addBootstrapToCheckoutFields($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as &$fieldset) {
        foreach ($fieldset as &$field) {
            foreach ($field['class'] as $text) {
                echo ($text . ' <br>');
            }
            $field['class'][] = 'form-group';
            $field['input_class'][] = 'form-control';
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}

Comment: This gives me a list of all the used classes expect for "form-row" I get the form-row-first, last and the other classes.. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The filter you have added for form fields only works for the billing form in the checkout page the billing form in the account section remains unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css. Simple css can fix this issue.

```
.woocommerce .form-row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```